# Getting oil residue out of a container

Tags: oil, cleaning

I have a ceramic oil bottle that I don't use.  It's just not as convenient as I hoped it would be.  I'd like to donate it, but it still has an oil residue inside it.  It has a long curved neck so sticking a bottle brush inside it isn't an option.  Is there a way to get the oil out or are my only options throwing it out or donating it with the oil residue?

Answer (score 2):

You can pour water and detergent inside, let it sit that way for a day to soften, then clean it by shaking the detergent solution vigorously and then filling it with water and emptying until the water comes out non-soapy. This should work, unless you let it sit for a long time empty, but with the residue of polyunsaturated oils inside. In that case, they can have gummed up.

If the brush problem comes because a straight brush can be stuck inside, but can't reach the nooks and the bottom, you could use a curved brush. These are sold to homebrewers in large sizes, I don't know if they are available for single bottles too.

Comment: I did try soaking it before I posted and when I finished rinsing it, the water came out clear so I thought I had done it. Sadly, when I put it upside down to dry, the counter ended up with oil all over. :(   I will look for the curved brush though.  Maybe that'll be a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use automatic dishwasher detergent, very hot water, let soak overnight, shake, empty and rinse with very hot water, upend on a skewer to drain dry.

Comment: This answer is identical to the Jan 31, 2014 one.

Comment: Not really an identical answer if rumtscho meant liquid dish detergent. Dishwasher detergent is much stronger and more alkaline. Whether it will work though is unknown until tried.